# Lag a value with Datavec transform

Tags: java, deeplearning4j, nd4j

I'm trying to figure out how to get a lagged value of a field as part of a datavec transform step.

Here is a little example built off the dl4j examples:

```
import org.datavec.api.records.reader.RecordReader;
import org.datavec.api.records.reader.impl.csv.CSVRecordReader;
import org.datavec.api.split.FileSplit;
import org.datavec.api.transform.TransformProcess;
import org.datavec.api.transform.schema.Schema;
import org.datavec.api.writable.Writable;
import org.datavec.local.transforms.LocalTransformExecutor;
import org.nd4j.linalg.io.ClassPathResource;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class myExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws  Exception {

        Schema inputDataSchema = new Schema.Builder()
            .addColumnString("DateTimeString")
            .addColumnsString("CustomerID", "MerchantID")
            .addColumnInteger("NumItemsInTransaction")
            .addColumnCategorical("MerchantCountryCode", Arrays.asList("USA","CAN","FR","MX"))
            .addColumnDouble("TransactionAmountUSD",0.0,null,false,false)   //$0.0 or more, no maximum limit, no NaN and no Infinite values
            .addColumnCategorical("FraudLabel", Arrays.asList("Fraud","Legit"))
            .build();

        TransformProcess tp = new TransformProcess.Builder(inputDataSchema)
            .removeAllColumnsExceptFor("DateTimeString","TransactionAmountUSD")
            .build();

        File inputFile = new ClassPathResource("BasicDataVecExample/exampledata.csv").getFile();

        //Define input reader and output writer:
        RecordReader rr = new CSVRecordReader(1, ',');
        rr.initialize(new FileSplit(inputFile));

        //Process the data:
        List<List<Writable>> originalData = new ArrayList<>();
        while(rr.hasNext()){
            originalData.add(rr.next());
        }

        List<List<Writable>> processedData = LocalTransformExecutor.execute(originalData, tp);

        int numRows = 5;

        System.out.println("=== BEFORE ===");

        for (int i=0;i<=numRows;i++) {
            System.out.println(originalData.get(i));
        }

        System.out.println("=== AFTER ===");
        for (int i=0;i<=numRows;i++) {
            System.out.println(processedData.get(i));
        }

    }

}
```

I'm looking to get a lagged value (ordered by `DateTimeString`) of `TransactionAmountUSD`

I was looking at sequenceMovingWindowReduce from the [docs](https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/datavec-transforms) but could not figure it out. Also could not really find any examples in the [examples repo](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/search?q=sequenceMovingWindowReduce&unscoped_q=sequenceMovingWindowReduce) that seemed to do anything similar to this.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to some help from Alex Black on the [dl4j gitter channel](https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j) i can post my own answer.

Tip to anyone new to dl4j - there is lots of good things to look at in the [tests code](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/blob/master/datavec/datavec-local/src/test/java/org/datavec/local/transforms/transform/sequence/TestConvertToSequence.java) too in addition to the examples and tutorials.

Here is my updated toy example code:

```
package org.datavec.transform.basic;

import org.datavec.api.records.reader.RecordReader;
import org.datavec.api.records.reader.impl.csv.CSVRecordReader;
import org.datavec.api.split.FileSplit;
import org.datavec.api.transform.TransformProcess;
import org.datavec.api.transform.schema.Schema;
import org.datavec.api.transform.sequence.comparator.NumericalColumnComparator;
import org.datavec.api.transform.transform.sequence.SequenceOffsetTransform;
import org.datavec.api.writable.Writable;
import org.datavec.local.transforms.LocalTransformExecutor;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.nd4j.linalg.io.ClassPathResource;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class myExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws  Exception {

        Schema inputDataSchema = new Schema.Builder()
            .addColumnString("DateTimeString")
            .addColumnsString("CustomerID", "MerchantID")
            .addColumnInteger("NumItemsInTransaction")
            .addColumnCategorical("MerchantCountryCode", Arrays.asList("USA","CAN","FR","MX"))
            .addColumnDouble("TransactionAmountUSD",0.0,null,false,false)   //$0.0 or more, no maximum limit, no NaN and no Infinite values
            .addColumnCategorical("FraudLabel", Arrays.asList("Fraud","Legit"))
            .build();

        TransformProcess tp = new TransformProcess.Builder(inputDataSchema)
            .removeAllColumnsExceptFor("CustomerID", "DateTimeString","TransactionAmountUSD")
            .stringToTimeTransform("DateTimeString","YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS", DateTimeZone.UTC)
            .convertToSequence(Arrays.asList("CustomerID"), new NumericalColumnComparator("DateTimeString"))
            .offsetSequence(Arrays.asList("TransactionAmountUSD"),1, SequenceOffsetTransform.OperationType.NewColumn)
            .build();

        File inputFile = new ClassPathResource("BasicDataVecExample/exampledata.csv").getFile();

        //Define input reader and output writer:
        RecordReader rr = new CSVRecordReader(0, ',');
        rr.initialize(new FileSplit(inputFile));

        //Process the data:
        List<List<Writable>> originalData = new ArrayList<>();
        while(rr.hasNext()){
            originalData.add(rr.next());
        }

        List<List<List<Writable>>> processedData = LocalTransformExecutor.executeToSequence(originalData, tp);

        System.out.println("=== BEFORE ===");

        for (int i=0;i<originalData.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(originalData.get(i));
        }

        System.out.println("=== AFTER ===");
        for (int i=0;i<processedData.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(processedData.get(i));
        }

    }

}
```

This should give some output like below where you can see a now col with the last value for the transaction amount for each customer id is added.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=56103:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\Documents\java_learning\dl4j-examples\datavec-examples\target\classes;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\datavec\datavec-api\1.0.0-beta3\datavec-api-1.0.0-beta3.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\jetbrains\annotations\13.0\annotations-13.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.6\commons-lang3-3.6.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.5\commons-io-2.5.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.21\slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\joda-time\joda-time\2.2\joda-time-2.2.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.12\snakeyaml-1.12.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\nd4j\jackson\1.0.0-beta3\jackson-1.0.0-beta3.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\woodstox\stax2-api\3.1.4\stax2-api-3.1.4.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\freemarker\freemarker\2.3.23\freemarker-2.3.23.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\nd4j\nd4j-common\1.0.0-beta3\nd4j-common-1.0.0-beta3.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\nd4j\nd4j-api\1.0.0-beta3\nd4j-api-1.0.0-beta3.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\google\flatbuffers\flatbuffers-java\1.9.0\flatbuffers-java-1.9.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\github\os72\protobuf-java-shaded-351\0.9\protobuf-java-shaded-351-0.9.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\github\os72\protobuf-java-util-shaded-351\0.9\protobuf-java-util-shaded-351-0.9.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.7\gson-2.7.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\2.6\objenesis-2.6.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\uk\com\robust-it\cloning\1.9.3\cloning-1.9.3.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\nd4j\nd4j-buffer\1.0.0-beta3\nd4j-buffer-1.0.0-beta3.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\bytedeco\javacpp\1.4.3\javacpp-1.4.3.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\nd4j\nd4j-context\1.0.0-beta3\nd4j-context-1.0.0-beta3.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\net\ericaro\neoitertools\1.0.0\neoitertools-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\clearspring\analytics\stream\2.7.0\stream-2.7.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\net\sf\opencsv\opencsv\2.3\opencsv-2.3.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\tdunning\t-digest\3.2\t-digest-3.2.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\it\unimi\dsi\fastutil\6.5.7\fastutil-6.5.7.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\datavec\datavec-spark_2.11\1.0.0-beta3_spark_1\datavec-spark_2.11-1.0.0-beta3_spark_1.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.11.12\scala-library-2.11.12.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-reflect\2.11.12\scala-reflect-2.11.12.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.9.13\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.9.13\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-sql_2.11\1.6.3\spark-sql_2.11-1.6.3.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-core_2.11\1.6.3\spark-core_2.11-1.6.3.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro-mapred\1.7.7\avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop2.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro-ipc\1.7.7\avro-ipc-1.7.7.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro\1.7.7\avro-1.7.7.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro-ipc\1.7.7\avro-ipc-1.7.7-tests.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\twitter\chill_2.11\0.5.0\chill_2.11-0.5.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\esotericsoftware\kryo\kryo\2.21\kryo-2.21.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\esotericsoftware\reflectasm\reflectasm\1.07\reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\esotericsoftware\minlog\minlog\1.2\minlog-1.2.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\twitter\chill-java\0.5.0\chill-java-0.5.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\xbean\xbean-asm5-shaded\4.4\xbean-asm5-shaded-4.4.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-client\2.2.0\hadoop-client-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-common\2.2.0\hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\commons-cli\commons-cli\1.2\commons-cli-1.2.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-math\2.1\commons-math-2.1.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\xmlenc\xmlenc\0.52\xmlenc-0.52.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\commons-configuration\commons-configuration\1.6\commons-configuration-1.6.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\commons-digester\commons-digester\1.8\commons-digester-1.8.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.7.0\commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils-core\1.8.0\commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-auth\2.2.0\hadoop-auth-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-hdfs\2.2.0\hadoop-hdfs-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\mortbay\jetty\jetty-util\6.1.26\jetty-util-6.1.26.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-app\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-common\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-yarn-client\2.2.0\hadoop-yarn-client-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-test-framework\jersey-test-framework-grizzly2\1.9\jersey-test-framework-grizzly2-1.9.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-test-framework\jersey-test-framework-core\1.9\jersey-test-framework-core-1.9.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-client\1.9\jersey-client-1.9.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-grizzly2\1.9\jersey-grizzly2-1.9.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\grizzly\grizzly-http\2.1.2\grizzly-http-2.1.2.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\grizzly\grizzly-framework\2.1.2\grizzly-framework-2.1.2.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\gmbal\gmbal-api-only\3.0.0-b023\gmbal-api-only-3.0.0-b023.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\external\management-api\3.0.0-b012\management-api-3.0.0-b012.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\grizzly\grizzly-http-server\2.1.2\grizzly-http-server-2.1.2.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\grizzly\grizzly-rcm\2.1.2\grizzly-rcm-2.1.2.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\grizzly\grizzly-http-servlet\2.1.2\grizzly-http-servlet-2.1.2.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\javax.servlet\3.1\javax.servlet-3.1.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-json\1.9\jersey-json-1.9.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jettison\jettison\1.1\jettison-1.1.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\stax\stax-api\1.0.1\stax-api-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-jaxrs\1.8.3\jackson-jaxrs-1.8.3.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-xc\1.8.3\jackson-xc-1.8.3.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\contribs\jersey-guice\1.9\jersey-guice-1.9.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-yarn-server-common\2.2.0\hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-yarn-api\2.2.0\hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-core\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-yarn-common\2.2.0\hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient\2.2.0\hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop\hadoop-annotations\2.2.0\hadoop-annotations-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-launcher_2.11\1.6.3\spark-launcher_2.11-1.6.3.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-network-common_2.11\1.6.3\spark-network-common_2.11-1.6.3.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-network-shuffle_2.11\1.6.3\spark-network-shuffle_2.11-1.6.3.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\fusesource\leveldbjni\leveldbjni-all\1.8\leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-unsafe_2.11\1.6.3\spark-unsafe_2.11-1.6.3.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jets3t\jets3t\0.7.1\jets3t-0.7.1.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\commons-httpclient\commons-httpclient\3.1\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\orbit\javax.servlet\3.0.0.v201112011016\javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.10\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.10\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.7.10\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\ning\compress-lzf\1.0.3\compress-lzf-1.0.3.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\xerial\snappy\snappy-java\1.1.2.6\snappy-java-1.1.2.6.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\net\jpountz\lz4\lz4\1.3.0\lz4-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\roaringbitmap\RoaringBitmap\0.5.11\RoaringBitmap-0.5.11.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\json4s\json4s-jackson_2.11\3.2.10\json4s-jackson_2.11-3.2.10.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\json4s\json4s-core_2.11\3.2.10\json4s-core_2.11-3.2.10.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\json4s\json4s-ast_2.11\3.2.10\json4s-ast_2.11-3.2.10.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scalap\2.11.0\scalap-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.11.0\scala-compiler-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\modules\scala-xml_2.11\1.0.1\scala-xml_2.11-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\modules\scala-parser-combinators_2.11\1.0.1\scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-server\1.9\jersey-server-1.9.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\asm\asm\3.1\asm-3.1.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-core\1.9\jersey-core-1.9.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\mesos\mesos\0.21.1\mesos-0.21.1-shaded-protobuf.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-all\4.0.29.Final\netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-core\3.1.2\metrics-core-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-jvm\3.1.2\metrics-jvm-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-json\3.1.2\metrics-json-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-graphite\3.1.2\metrics-graphite-3.1.2.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-scala_2.11\2.5.1\jackson-module-scala_2.11-2.5.1.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\thoughtworks\paranamer\paranamer\2.6\paranamer-2.6.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\ivy\ivy\2.4.0\ivy-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\oro\oro\2.0.8\oro-2.0.8.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\tachyonproject\tachyon-client\0.8.2\tachyon-client-0.8.2.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\tachyonproject\tachyon-underfs-hdfs\0.8.2\tachyon-underfs-hdfs-0.8.2.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\tachyonproject\tachyon-underfs-s3\0.8.2\tachyon-underfs-s3-0.8.2.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\tachyonproject\tachyon-underfs-local\0.8.2\tachyon-underfs-local-0.8.2.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\net\razorvine\pyrolite\4.9\pyrolite-4.9.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\net\sf\py4j\py4j\0.9\py4j-0.9.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-catalyst_2.11\1.6.3\spark-catalyst_2.11-1.6.3.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\janino\janino\2.7.8\janino-2.7.8.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\janino\commons-compiler\2.7.8\commons-compiler-2.7.8.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-column\1.7.0\parquet-column-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-common\1.7.0\parquet-common-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-encoding\1.7.0\parquet-encoding-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-generator\1.7.0\parquet-generator-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-hadoop\1.7.0\parquet-hadoop-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-format\2.3.0-incubating\parquet-format-2.3.0-incubating.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\parquet\parquet-jackson\1.7.0\parquet-jackson-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\spark-project\spark\unused\1.0.0\unused-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\20.0\guava-20.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\google\inject\guice\4.0\guice-4.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java\2.6.1\protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.2\commons-collections-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\commons-net\commons-net\3.1\commons-net-3.1.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-core\2.2.11\jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.11\jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\typesafe\akka\akka-actor_2.11\2.3.16\akka-actor_2.11-2.3.16.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\typesafe\akka\akka-remote_2.11\2.3.16\akka-remote_2.11-2.3.16.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\uncommons\maths\uncommons-maths\1.2.2a\uncommons-maths-1.2.2a.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\typesafe\akka\akka-slf4j_2.11\2.3.16\akka-slf4j_2.11-2.3.16.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty\3.10.4.Final\netty-3.10.4.Final.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.5.1\jackson-core-2.5.1.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.5.1\jackson-databind-2.5.1.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.5.1\jackson-annotations-2.5.1.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.1.0\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.16.1\commons-compress-1.16.1.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-math3\3.5\commons-math3-3.5.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\curator\curator-recipes\2.8.0\curator-recipes-2.8.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\curator\curator-framework\2.8.0\curator-framework-2.8.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\curator\curator-client\2.8.0\curator-client-2.8.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\zookeeper\zookeeper\3.4.6\zookeeper-3.4.6.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\jline\jline\0.9.94\jline-0.9.94.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\typesafe\config\1.3.0\config-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\datavec\datavec-hadoop\1.0.0-beta3\datavec-hadoop-1.0.0-beta3.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\datavec\datavec-local\1.0.0-beta3\datavec-local-1.0.0-beta3.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\codepoetics\protonpack\1.15\protonpack-1.15.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\datavec\datavec-arrow\1.0.0-beta3\datavec-arrow-1.0.0-beta3.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\nd4j\nd4j-arrow\1.0.0-beta3\nd4j-arrow-1.0.0-beta3.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-yaml\2.6.5\jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-xml\2.6.5\jackson-dataformat-xml-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-jaxb-annotations\2.6.5\jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-joda\2.6.5\jackson-datatype-joda-2.6.5.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\com\carrotsearch\hppc\0.8.1\hppc-0.8.1.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\arrow\arrow-vector\0.11.0\arrow-vector-0.11.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-buffer\4.1.22.Final\netty-buffer-4.1.22.Final.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-common\4.1.22.Final\netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\arrow\arrow-memory\0.11.0\arrow-memory-0.11.0.jar;C:\Users\amaguire\.m2\repository\org\apache\arrow\arrow-format\0.11.0\arrow-format-0.11.0.jar" org.datavec.transform.basic.myExample
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
=== BEFORE ===
[2016-01-01 17:00:00.000, 830a7u3, u323fy8902, 1, USA, 100.00, Legit]
[2016-01-01 18:03:01.256, 830a7u3, 9732498oeu, 3, FR, 73.20, Legit]
[2016-01-03 02:53:32.231, 78ueoau32, w234e989, 1, USA, 1621.00, Fraud]
[2016-01-03 09:30:16.832, t842uocd, 9732498oeu, 4, USA, 43.19, Legit]
[2016-01-04 23:01:52.920, t842uocd, cza8873bm, 10, MX, 159.65, Legit]
[2016-01-05 02:28:10.648, t842uocd, fgcq9803, 6, CAN, 26.33, Fraud]
[2016-01-05 10:15:36.483, rgc707ke3, tn342v7, 2, USA, -0.90, Legit]
=== AFTER ===
[[1451948512920, t842uocd, 159.65, 43.19], [1451960890648, t842uocd, 26.33, 159.65]]
[[1451671381256, 830a7u3, 73.20, 100.00]]
[]
[]

Process finished with exit code 0
```